# bash awk replace gsub

Tags: regex, bash, awk, replace, gsub

I am trying to figure out what I am not doing correct.

```
test="This is a test"
mytest=$(awk -v test="${test}" 'BEGIN{gsub("This is","This is not",test)}')
printf "My Test = $mytest\n"
```

This is something part of something bigger, but I am trying to understand why I can't get this to work. $mytest is empty. Eventually I want to regex /This is a test/ but I can't even get this simple to work. It is not erroring.

Comment: `mytest="${test/This is/This is not}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should output the result, otherwise, you have nothing to give variable `mytest`. To fix that, add `print test` after your `gsub(....)`.

So it would be:

```
mytest=$(awk ... BEGIN{gsub(...);print test}')
```

Comment: Except `awk` when not told to operate on a file, operates on `STDIN`, which in this case is the tty executing the command.  Need to at least send it one line to "work" on - `$ echo | awk -v test="this is a test" 'BEGIN { gsub("this is", "this is not", test); } { print test }'`

Comment: Never mind my previous comment - if you put your code in the `BEGIN` block, it executes regardless of whether the command has input fed to it or not.  Either way, the key to OP's issue of getting no output: his awk script has no instruction to emit any output.

Comment: @dossy you can do output in `BEGIN` block without reading input file or stdin. pls do some test.

Comment: Thank You. I just needed to ";print test" and it worked.